# can not get my custom taglib to work

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib

I created my taglib using the command: "grails create-taglib TimeTag"
And a skeleton tag was created called TimeTagLib.

```
package com.buffer

class TimeTagLib {
    static final namespace = 'myTag'
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
    //static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'none']]
    def weekNo = {attrs, body ->
        date = new Date()
        def calendar = date.toCalendar()
        def week = calendar.get(calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
        out << body() << calendar.format('yy') + String.format("%02d", week+attrs.offset)
    }
}
```

and in the gsp-file I added this line:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="availW01" title="${timetaglib.weekno(offset: '0')}" />
```

And I get the following message:
Message

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error evaluating expression [timetaglib.weekno(offset: '0')] on line [38]: Cannot invoke method weekno() on null object
Caused by
Cannot invoke method weekno() on null object
```

I just don't know what to do... I thought I followed the documentation well enough but apparently not.
I have grails-3.2.4

===================THE SOLUTION ==================

TagLib:

```
package com.buffer

class TimeTagLib {
    static final namespace = 'myTag'
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
    //static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'none']]
    def weekNo = {attrs, body ->
        Date date = new Date()
        def calendar = date.toCalendar()
        def week = calendar.get(calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
        out  << String.format("V%02d", (week+(attrs.offset as Integer)))
    }
}
```

The GSP:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="availW01" title="${myTag.weekNo(offset: "0")}" />
```

Comment: To call your tag use: `${myTag.weekNo(offset: 0)}`

Comment: Yes, you're quite wright but I also had more bugs as you can read about in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a simple, but fundamental, misunderstanding of how to call your custom tag library. Instead of using the class name you need to use the `namespace`, so your tag library (in your question) would be called as such: `${myTag.weekNo(offset: 0)}` or `<myTag:weekNo offset="0" />`.

Comment: Ok, I would say -none understanding at all-. But I was aware of that and also tested with myTag but didn't recognize that I got a different error that time. I couldn't add the parameter attrs.offset to the integer weekNo without first casting the parameter to integer. Thanks to you I had to check once more and then I recognized the different errormessage.